# How to create nested JSON response using Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express

I am using Node.js and My-SQL to create a rest API. I want my response like nested JSON object which will easy to read on my frontend. I tried with for loop, but it does not give me the proper result, is there any plugins available to format this response or is there any easy way to do this nested JSON response.

my SQL query is

```
var sql ='SELECT comments.comment_id,comments.photo_id,comments.comment_message,comments.comment_date ,tb_users.username as comment_usename,tb_users.first_name as comment_firstname ,tb_users.profile_icon as comment_profile_icon,tb_reply.id,tb_reply.comment_id,tb_reply.photo_id,tb_reply.reply_message,tb_reply.create_date as reply_date,u2.username as r_usename,u2.first_name as r_first_name,u2.profile_icon as r_profile_icon '+
' FROM comments LEFT JOIN tb_reply ON tb_reply.comment_id=comments.comment_id '+
' INNER JOIN tb_users ON tb_users.id=comments.user_id '+
' LEFT JOIN tb_users u2 ON tb_reply.user_id = u2.id '+
' WHERE comments.photo_id= '+photoid+' ORDER BY comments.comment_id DESC LIMIT ' +(pageNo-1)*20+ ', 20 '
```

and I am getting the response is like

```
[
     {
        "comment_id": 20,
        "photo_id": 68,
        "comment_message": "@singh wow   nod.gif ⛑  ",
        "comment_date": "2018-06-03T11:12:50.000Z",
        "comment_usename": "love132@gmail.com",
        "comment_firstname": "love",
        "comment_profile_icon": "",
        "id": 1,
        "reply_message": "lol ",
        "reply_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "r_usename": "love1@gmail.com",
        "r_first_name": "sud3",
        "r_profile_icon": ""
    },
    {
        "comment_id": 20,
        "photo_id": 68,
        "comment_message": "@singh wow   nod.gif ⛑  ",
        "comment_date": "2018-06-03T11:12:50.000Z",
        "comment_usename": "love132@gmail.com",
        "comment_firstname": "love",
        "comment_profile_icon": "",
        "id": 2,
        "reply_message": "lol hahahhaha . ",
        "reply_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "r_usename": "love@gmail.com",
        "r_first_name": "sud4",
        "r_profile_icon": ""
    },
    {
        "comment_id": 20,
        "photo_id": 68,
        "comment_message": "@singh wow   nod.gif ⛑  ",
        "comment_date": "2018-06-03T11:12:50.000Z",
        "comment_usename": "love132@gmail.com",
        "comment_firstname": "love",
        "comment_profile_icon": "",
        "id": 3,
        "reply_message": "r2t3s",
        "reply_date": "2018-06-01T18:42:49.000Z",
        "r_usename": "love132@gmail.com",
        "r_first_name": "love",
        "r_profile_icon": ""
    },
```

but I need like

```
[
    {
        "comment_id": 20,
        "photo_id": 68,
        "comment_message": "@singh wow   nod.gif ⛑  ",
        "comment_date": "2018-06-03T11:12:50.000Z",
        "comment_username": "love132@gmail.com",
        "comment_first_name": "love",
        "comment_profile_icon": "",
        "reply" [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "reply_message": "lol ",
                "reply_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "r_usename": "love1@gmail.com",
                "r_first_name": "sud",
                "r_profile_icon": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "reply_message": "lol hahahhaha . ",
                "reply_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "r_usename": "love@gmail.com",
                "r_first_name": "sud4",
                "r_profile_icon": ""
            },
            {      
                "id": 3,
                "reply_message": "r2t3s",
                "reply_date": "2018-06-01T18:42:49.000Z",
                "r_usename": "love132@gmail.com",
                "r_first_name": "love",
                "r_profile_icon": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st step query all the comments make it equal to a variable call result
2. For loop on the result array, call the query to load all the replies that have foreign key to the comment and save the results as result[x].reply